# Cannot Save Excel to Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel, save

One of my users is having an issue saving to Sharepoint with some very specific parameters.

the problem is related to saving only from within excel if a document has been opened from SP.  She is unable to edit the document and simply click Save.

when she tries, the progress bar appears but never goes anywhere.  eventually an error relating to the the web folder being disconnected appears.

if the excel file is saved locally, she is able to upload the file using the SP interface.

Also, she is able to open and edit other MS Office documents with no problems, this one is only related to Excel.